# What should be done about the size tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tagwiki

What is the [size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/size) tag? It has no wiki summary, and I can't really seem to find any apparent pattern among all of the questions that have been tagged with [size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/size), at least not immediately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems pretty much irredeemably broken.

Looking over the first few questions tagged that way it seems to cover

- stretchy symbols \left\right stuff could be tagged [delimiters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delimiters) if not already
- large file sizes could be tagged [memory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory) or [database](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) or ...
- box sizing stuff. could be tagged [boxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boxes) if not already

I suppose if someone is bored on a rainy afternoon could go through and re-tag then delete [size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/size) ?

Comment: Zapping [tag:size] is probably a mod job, but first I guess needs the new tags adding

Comment: Or they are about [tag:fontsize] and [tag:scaling].

Comment: @JosephWright: Won't the tag be deleted automatically if it's not used by any questions anymore?

Comment: @MartinSchröder It's better to blacklist the tag, so that this thread need not be unburied one day ;)

Answer (score 7):

I started re-tagging the question, a bunch a day, about two dozens, so that it doesn't fill the front page completely. I don't think more interaction is needed, I'll let Joseph know when I'm finish so that the tag can be officially zapped.

Being there, I discovered that we should probably synonymise:

[dimension-expressions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dimension-expressions) -> [dimensions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dimensions)

[unit-of-measure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-of-measure) -> [units](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/units)